# CBV или функция. Что вы предпочитаете?

Tags: django

Просто интересно, что вы предпочитаете использовать в представлениях, функции или CBV и почему?

Comment: so не для опросов.

Answer (score 1):

Моего мнения здесь нет, представлены разные видения различных людей !!!

Мнение разного комьюнити:

https://toster.ru/q/333704

https://djbook.ru/forum/topic/4570/

https://toster.ru/q/514410

ENG версия ответа на вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788801/in-a-new-django-project-should-i-use-class-based-or-function-based-views

Перевод:
В новом проекте Django следует использовать представления на основе класса или функции?

В новом проекте Django мне просто интересно, следует ли использовать классные представления (CBV) или функциональные представления (FBV).

Согласно документации Django:

```
Представления на основе классов предоставляют альтернативный способ реализации представлений как объектов Python вместо функций. Они не заменяют функциональные представления, но имеют определенные отличия и преимущества по сравнению с представлениями на основе функций
```

Что, кажется, противоречит python Zen 'Существует только один способ сделать это'

Итак, что лучше?

Пока я вижу только три возможности:

```
Всегда использовать FBV

Это означает, что вообще не использовать общие представления (поскольку они основаны на классах с 1,5)

Всегда используя CBV:

У кого есть определенные проблемы с определением заказов обработки запросов. См

http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/djangos-cbvs-were-a-mistake/

Я также думаю, что создание всей иерархии классов не очень хорошо для производительности. В этом случае я также задал себе вопрос, почему FBV еще не устарели?

Ввод общего CBV в FBV, согласно

https://gist.github.com/spookylukey/2596285

что приводит к большому количеству жестокого шаблонного кода
```

Вы видите какие-либо другие способы, или кто-нибудь знает, куда идут представления?

Ответ ENG версии:

Это вопрос мнения, лично я не согласен с Luke Plant на этом, и я влюбился в Class Based Views. Я думаю, что большая часть сопротивления сообщества Django с нетерпением их приняла из-за того, что они не могли легко увидеть, как они работали (реализация использует много миксинов и может быть трудно следовать), и документации не хватало, что и я думаю, что было много недоразумений в отношении Generic CBV и простых CBV. (в течение долгого времени, когда вы Googled "django class based views", первые результаты касались общих представлений).

Теперь документация становится намного лучше, и инструменты, доступные для их понимания, великолепны (см. ccbv.co.uk или pudb).

Я предлагаю учиться и использовать Class Based Views по тем же причинам, которые люди предлагают OOP, это уменьшает повторение кода и увеличивает повторное использование кода (наследование, mixins)... другими словами, оно DRY.

Еще одна вещь, стоит проверить, как другие проекты используют CBV... один из моих последних фаворитов - django-oscar, который использует их для хорошего эффекта.

---

UPD: См. комментарии, там интересно !!!

Comment: DRY можно обеспечивать и с помощью выноса повторяющегося кода в функции-хелперы, а CBV не нужны и вообще вредны, потому что создают запутанную мешанину из этих ваших наследований и вообще ограничивают гибкость проекта. Всегда использую только FBV